# C# Client prints from any source. File goes to print service

Tags: c#, printing, client-server

I seen this at library where a patron is able to print from any source. That file goes to a print server. I kept searching Stackoverflow but always seems to have the search result from a web application to print server side and that is not what I am looking for.

Does the application on server side waits for print queue then pauses it till client okays the prints on the print station? If so what is the direction I need to look into for C# application?

Thank you.

Solving the logical part of this before I code.